Unexcept retopo for STL export
I made a model and exported it in stl.
When I imported the model I exported before, I found that a triangular mesh appeared on the surface filled with the shortcut key f at the bottom

you can get my file from 
How can I export to avoid this phenomenon

Hello mengyuanlan, it's perfectly normal, STL format is a triangle based system, your "clean face" is a multiple triangles faces that blender consider just as one.

@FredI.R.F Oh, do you mean that this bread actually contains a lot of triangles, but Blender didn't show the boundaries？

Exactly that's hiding by blender. It's very common for exporter to triangulate you know.
